# How to Parse text data and store the same in array with splitting in j2me?

Tags: text, split, java-me

How to Parse text data and store the same in array with splitting in j2me?
I have proceeded with the following code and I get to see all the text data but can't go any further. Can you guide me?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.io.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
/**
 * @author sagar
 */
public class Matches extends MIDlet {

    String url = "***I cant show the link***";
    private Display display;

    public Matches() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    }
    /**
     * This will be invoked when we start the MIDlet
     */
    public void startApp() {
        try {
            getViaHttpConnection(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Handle Exceptions any other way you like.
            System.out.println("IOException " + e);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Pause, discontinue ....
     */
    public void pauseApp() {}
    /**
     * Destroy must cleanup everything.
     */
    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {}
    /**
     * read url via Httpconnection
     */
    public void getViaHttpConnection(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpConnection con = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        String str = new String();
        TextBox tb = null;

        try {
            con = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
            is = con.openInputStream();
            int ch;
            while((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
            buff.append((char) ch);
            str = buff.toString();
            }
            System.out.println(str);
            tb = new TextBox("Matches", str, 1024, 0);

        } finally {
            if(is != null) {
            is.close();
            }
            if(con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        }// display the contents of the file in a text box.
        display.setCurrent(tb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sagar , What exactly you want to do here, can you be more specific with an example.

Comment: I want to  parse the text data (&isrecent=1&r_file_1=enau1605&r_typ_1=ODI&r_num_1=Final&r_tma_1=England&r_ven_1=Bridgetown&r_tmb_1=Australia&r_tmas_1=ENG&r_tmbs_1=AUS&r_date_1=May 16&r_result_1=ENG beat AUS by 7 wickets&r_ser_1=ICC World Twenty20, 2010&r_tma_score_1=148/3&r_tmb_score_1=147/6) in proper displayable format.